# WH_KEYBOARD_LL hook, possible to use heap memory inside?

Tags: c, windows, input, keyboard-hook

I need to set a variable in my program's main() by the result of a WM_KEYUP/DOWN inside of LowLevelKeyboardProc().  I need to set a float variable to 1 on KEYDOWN and 0 on KEYUP, that float being allocated in main().  I don't think it's a good idea to use global variables, so is it possible to do this, or is there an easier method of getting keypresses quickly?  I am using C.

Comment: I don't think you have much choice here, as hooks don't allow to pass a custom parameter to callback proc. As you usually have only one keyboard hook per process, using the global variable is reasonable (and the only) choice.

Comment: Then it's safe to say those variables should also be declared 'volatile'?

Comment: Yes, that would make sense.